# C++ error while compiling android source

Tags: android, c++, compiler-construction, android-source

i'm trying to compile android 4.1 for my device, but i get this error:

```
target thumb C++: libandroid_runtime <= frameworks/base/core/jni/Time.cpp
target thumb C++: libandroid_runtime <= frameworks/base/core/jni/com_android_internal_content_NativeLibraryHelper.cpp
frameworks/base/core/jni/Time.cpp: In member function 'android::String8 android::Time::format(char const*, const android::strftime_locale*) const':
frameworks/base/core/jni/Time.cpp:91:61: error: 'strftime_tz' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [out/target/product/galaxysl/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_runtime_intermediates/Time.o] Errore 1
make: *** Attesa per i processi non terminati....
```

How can i fix these problems ? I've to declare strftime_tz in Time.cpp but i don't know to do that. There's the part of Time.cpp:

```
String8 
Time::format(const char *format, const struct strftime_locale *locale) const
{
    char buf[257];
    int n = strftime_tz(buf, 257, format, &(this->t), locale);
    if (n > 0) {
        return String8(buf);
    } else {
        return String8();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like `strftime_tz` is an extension to the standard C function `strftime`. I don't think *you* should declare it, but find out where in the support library it already is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to include `#include <cutils/tztime.h>`

Comment: maybe along with `#include <tzfile.h>`

Comment: there's already a string that says #include <cutils/tztime.h> in the file. here you cane see the entire file:
https://www.codeaurora.org/git/projects/qrd-gb-dsds-7225/repository/revisions/cc99b832a941dc8cbb86f1607d04eb87935ddbfd/entry/android/frameworks/base/core/jni/Time.cpp